# Is it possible to find Longest common subsequence of all pair of splits of a string in better than $O(n^3)$?

Tags: subsequences, string-matching

I have  a string $a_0a_1..a_{n-1}$

Lets say we split the string at pos $i$, so the string are

$a_0a_1....a_{i}$ and $a_{i+1}a_{i+2}....a_{n-1}$

Now I need to compute:

$max(LCS(a_0a_1....a_{i} , a_{i+1}a_{i+2}....a_{n-1}))$ for all $i$ in $[0,n-1]$

common LCS algorithms takes $O(n^2)$ time. so if we use that n times it would be $O(n^3)$.
Given that there are many overlapping parts of string can we do better ?

I don't need the subsequence , I just need the max subsequence length and position of splitting.

Comment: `Given that the [strings are almost the same for any i and i+1, can we do better?` What are the cases where *split at $i+1$* yields a result different from *split at $i$*?

Comment: exactly that is the point , those cases can be analysed in O(1) or O(n) by some incremental update  so there should be something better than O(n^2) for every split after spending O(n^2) once.

Comment: anyways never mind I found a  solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545364/longest-repeated-non-overlapping-subsequence/69623429#69623429?newreg=3bd877ea00de47ec99b056e8e3c04c86